# add trailing slash traffic server

Tags: trailing-slash, apache-traffic-server

How should I add o a trailing slash at the end of a URL in apache traffic server?  I checked that in normal Apache using rewrite and regex with the following configuration, if the user does not add a slash at the end of the url, it can be entered in different directories without error. But in server traffic, unfortunately, the syntax has changed and I found the following configuration, but it didn't work. Is this a bug or can it be done by modifying config?

`example task:  example.co/text/fast   redirect to  example.co/test/fast/ EXAMPLE – REDIRECT ALL URLS THAT DOESN’T HAVE A TRAILING SLASH TO URLS WITH A TRAILING SLASH in apache`

`RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]`

EXAMPLE – REDIRECT ALL URLS THAT DOESN’T HAVE A TRAILING SLASH TO URLS WITH A TRAILING SLASH in Traffic server
(this regex can recognize slash)-(it didnt work)

`cond %{CLIENT-URL:PATH} /^([^.]*[^/])$/ set-redirect 301 http://different_origin.example.com/%{CLIENT-URL:PATH}/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add trailing slash from URL of apache traffic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76986905/add-trailing-slash-from-url-of-apache-traffic-server)

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`cond %{SEND_RESPONSE_HDR_HOOK}
`enter code here`cond %{CLIENT-URL:PATH} /^([^.]*[^/])$/
`enter code here`set-redirect 301 %[CLIENT-URL}/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).